# Splitting strings with Javascript without using for loop

Tags: javascript

I have following string:

```
var myString = " https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  "
```

ANd I would like to get the following array:

```
var myArray = ["https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg","https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg", "https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg".
```

Any ideas on how  I would do that?

Tried this:

```
myArray.split(/(\s+)/).filter( function(e) { return e.trim().length > 0; } );
```

But I get `t` when I do `console.log(myArray[1])`

Comment: Tried anything ?

Comment: "I have following string". No you don't. You can't have that code in any javascript anywhere without getting a syntax error.

Comment: Does your string really have all that whitespace?

Comment: is your string correct? having space between 2 urls?

Comment: Um, that is not a valid string in JavaScript since it has line feeds.

Comment: if your string has space between url then just do the left and right trim of string and split by " ".you will get array.

Comment: @epascarello it's a valid string, that just isn't a valid way to create that string.  He could just replace the quotes with back-ticks and it will work - see get-off-my-lawn's answer

Comment: for what you tried, don't you mean to start that line with `myString`?

Comment: Your code works if you change `myArray.split` to `myString.split`

Comment: @imjosh I know how to make it valid, just stating the obvious it is not valid in the code above.

Answer (score 4):

You can `trim()` the string first, then split on whitespace. This saves you from having to loop over the results again `map()`:

```js
var myString = ` https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  `

console.log(myString.trim().split(/\s+/))
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split on the new lines:

```js
var myString = ` https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  `

var result = myString.split(/\r\n|\n/).map(i => i.trim())

// Result of all items
console.log(result)

// Result of first item in the array
console.log(result[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string has all that whitespace (and therefore would need to be quoted with back-ticks (`` ` ``)):

```
var myString = ` https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  `

myString.trim().split(/\s+/)
```

First, this gets rid or whitespace on the ends of `myString`, then it splits on any group of whitespace (`\s`) characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trim split filter and map to achive it.

```
var myString = ` https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  `

myString.trim().split(/\r\n|\n/).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: That's not what the OP's input string looks like and this won't work not the OP's string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match the substrings starting with `https` and ending with `jpg` , this will match them even if they are in a single line :

```js
var myString = `https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg`

var result = myString.match(/https(.*)jpg/g)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple reg exp to match anything by spaces would get what you want.

```js
var myString = ` https://image.ibb.co/fShWGd/samhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/iDbDUy/ramhily.jpg
                 https://image.ibb.co/cvbf9y/devoly.jpg  `

console.log(myString.match(/[^\s]+/g))
```